# Adjusting width to aspect-ratio constrained content in a vertical flex box

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I don't understand why, with the code below, the `svg-container` element, constrained to an `aspect-ratio` of `1/1`, doesn't enlarge its parent element `top`. It vertically fills the `top` element as I need it to do, but doesn't enlarge its width.

Currently, the width of the parent `module` element is determined by the total width of the child elements of `bottom`, which is what I would expect. Except that the calculated width of `svg-container` is larger than `bottom`, and I would expect `top` and consequently `module` to adjust to this larger width.

In the Dev Tools I clearly see the effect of `aspect-ratio`, because the bounding box for `svg-container` is larger than its parents (the blue box overflows to the right and left). But the `top` element doesn't resize its width to accomodate its children, although its width is set to `auto`.

Setting `height: 100%` or `width: 100%` on `svg` doesn't help and I don't believe it's needed, because `svg-container` already has the proper dimensions. It simply doesn't resize its parent.

I've submitted this whole thing to ChatGPT and got this reply:

> Since the .module element has justify-content: space-between applied, it tries to distribute the available space between its flex items (top and bottom). However, the width: auto property on the .module element prevents it from expanding to accommodate the wider width of the .svg-container.

This resulted in the suggestion to replace `width: auto` in `.module` with `flex-grow: 1`. That didn't change anything, and I was then informed that this is impossible to do in CSS.

I don't understand why vertically distributing items in a flex box would prevent the items from horizontally expanding the flex box. Is it by design, and is it possible to achieve what I need in CSS?

```css
/*
Extra wrapper needed for rounded borders because parent has overflow-x: auto
*/
.module-wrapper {
}

.module {
  border-radius: 0.5rem;

  /* Needed for absolute positioning of close button */
  position: relative;

  /* Hide corners */
  overflow-y: hidden;

  /* Vertically distribute top and bottom */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;

  /* Fill entire available space in parent */
  height: 100%;
  
  width: auto;
}

.top {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.svg-container {
  /* Push <controls> to the bottom */
  flex-grow: 1;

  /* Keep svg element centered */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
}

.bottom {
  /* Container for more elements */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="module-wrapper">
    <div class="module">
        <button class="close"/>
        <div class="top">
            <div class="svg-container">
                <svg />
            </div>
            <div class="controls" />
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The way you have your code the svg has by default a size of 300 x 150. You will need to add a viewBox  and also maybe a height. Otherwise it will collapse to 0. In order to understand what happens add borders outlines or background colors to the elements.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking at this stuff with multicolored backgrounds and borders for 48 hours. I still don't understand why the parent doesn't resize to contain the child. BTW, there is a viewBox on the `svg`.

Comment: Can you explain what you would like to achieve? And update the HTML in you example by inserting something into the closed elements. What is the content of the button element?

Comment: As I explained, I am trying to understand how to make a parent element adapt its dimensions to its svg child element. After 100 attempts I abandoned the idea of doing this with CSS and fixed it in JavaScript.